# Find keywords in paragraphs of text (in Excel)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

Edit: All answers work great, but for a big dataset the macro approach worked better. Try all of them and see what works best for you.

I'm trying to solve this problem in Excel for performance (I have done it in R but it is slow). Basically, I need to match each keyword (from a list of keywords) against the text (essentially paragraphs) in a column. 
Here's an illustration:

[image]

The above data are in the source of this question in text form,
suitable for copy and paste.

I've been looking to some text functions (like FIND and SEARCH but they only return positions) so I'm not sure if this can be done in Excel.

Comment: Seriously, do you want the output for`A6` in `E5` (because the output for `A5` is “none”)?

Comment: @G-Man yes, sorry if that was not clear.

Comment: I have a pure formula solution using `TEXTJOIN` but without removing empty results, which means `E5` empty and the output for `A6` in E6. Later you can manually (or through a simple script) delete those empty results. Tell me if you are interested.

Comment: @A.S.H of course I am interested :) I can later remove empty values yes. But that was just an example, unfortunately, with my data I can't concatenate every _keyword_ in a single cell using TEXTJOIN (I have 700K _keywords_).

Comment: Yeah difficult to know a priori if it will work on your dataset but I will post a working formula on a reasonable test set so you can check it.

Comment: `TEXTJOIN` would be a good solution here like `=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IFERROR(IF(SEARCH($C$2:$C$20,A2),$C$2:$C$20),""))` for E2, however: knowing that there is a HUGE database to go with, the 32767-character limit may be a problem... also going for so big arrays may end in freezing excel. I don't think that there is a good solution without VBA :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this short macro:

```
Sub KeyWord()
    Dim Na As Long, Nc As Long, ary, s As String
    Dim r As Range, a, i As Long, outpt As String

    Na = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Nc = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    ReDim ary(1 To Nc)
    i = 1
    For Each r In Range("C1:C" & Nc)
        ary(i) = r.Text
        i = i + 1
    Next r

    For i = 1 To Na
        s = Cells(i, "A").Value
        outpt = ""
        For Each a In ary
            If InStr(1, s, a) > 0 Then
                outpt = outpt & "," & a
            End If
        Next a
        If outpt = "" Then
        Else
            Cells(i, "E").Value = Mid(outpt, 2)
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

for example:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

Our little trick to capture only full words is to surround each keyword with spaces and each sentence with spaces.

This means that *[space]* the *[space]* will not match *theater*!:

```
Sub KeyWord_II_TheSequel()
    Dim Na As Long, Nc As Long, ary, s As String
    Dim r As Range, a, i As Long, outpt As String

    Na = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Nc = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    ReDim ary(1 To Nc)
    i = 1
    For Each r In Range("C1:C" & Nc)
        ary(i) = r.Text
        ary(i) = " " & ary(i) & " "
        i = i + 1
    Next r

    For i = 1 To Na
        s = Cells(i, "A").Value
        s = " " & s & " "
        outpt = ""
        For Each a In ary
            If InStr(1, s, a) > 0 Then
                outpt = outpt & "," & a
            End If
        Next a
        If outpt = "" Then
        Else
            Cells(i, "E").Value = Mid(outpt, 2)
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your macro! It takes about 30s for each 100 rows in A with my PC, not bad! :) One question, would it be possible to extract words and not strings? I mean, if you had **_junks_** in column `A` do **NOT** match **_junk_** in column `C`. So instead of `InStr(1, s, a) > 0` it would have to be something else.

Comment: @Hoju  I do not understand.

Comment: In your example, if you have `or all` as a keyword in column `C`, it would give a match for `E$13` because the macro is looking for a substring. Would it be possible to look for words instead of substrings? So it would only give a match `for all` but not `or all`.

Comment: @Hoju  Yes there is a pretty standard way to capture **words** rather than **arbitrary substrings**.  Check back later.

Comment: @Hoju  See my **EDIT#1**

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer:

Difficult to estimate the performance of the following "array formula" on huge set of keywords. It works on a reasonable dataset and yields "correct" results.

The **Array Formula** for `E2` (Then autofill column E) is:

```
E2:
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,REPT(C$2:C$99999,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C$2:C$99999,A2))))
```

<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd>

As I said it was tested on a "reasonably large" set, say few thousands, So I posted it as a general solution for similar situations but I have doubts for your huge set of 700k (!).

Also it is probably recommendable to not keep the formulas but only use them for calculation, then fix the values and finally remove the empty cells. HTH

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I get what you are trying to do but it doesn't work for me. This is what I get: [error](http://i.imgur.com/qiQuSBf.png)

Comment: @Hoju from the attached figure I can see that you did not enter it as **array formula**. To enter it as such, edit the cell `E2` then press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`. Afterwards, copy/paste the cell down the column. When the cell has an array formula, the formula bar shows it enclosed with `{...}`

Comment: couldn't get this to work either.

Answer (score 2):

I’ll assume that your display showing the output for`A6` in `E5`
(because the output for `A5` is “none”) is an error,
and you really want the output for`A6` in `E6`.

I find it unnatural, having the keywords in a column. 
The output for `Ai` is in `Ei`,
and the value in `Ci`
doesn’t really have anything to do with the other things in Row *`i`*. 
It’s more of an *m*×*n* situation,
where you have *m* cells (paragraphs) of text to search in,
and *n* keywords to look for. 
Well, we have ways of handling that.

My solution uses *n* +1 helper columns. 
Since *n* here is 5, that means 6 helper columns,
which could be Columns `F` through `K`. 
(As usual with helper columns, you can put them wherever you want —
you can put them in Columns `AA` through `AF` if you want —
and you can hide them.)

The first one (`F`) is left blank. 
Enter

```
=OFFSET($C$1, COLUMN()-COLUMN($F:$F), 0)
```

into cell `G1` and drag/fill to the right, to `K1`. 
This uses the current column number
(relative to the beginning of the block of helper columns)
as an index into Column `C`, the keywords,
thereby replicating the keywords in Row 1 (cells `G1` through `K1`).

Next, enter

```
=F2 & IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(G$1, $A2)), ", " & G$1, "")
```

into cell `G2`. 
Drag/fill to the right, to cell `K2`,
and then down to cover the *m* rows that have data in Column `A`. 
This searches the paragraph in Column `A` of the current row
for the  *i*  th keyword, which is in Row 1 of the current column. 
If it finds it (i.e., if `SEARCH(…)` returns a number;
i.e., if `ISNUMBER(SEARCH(…))` is true),
it generates the keyword, preceded by a comma and a space. 
If it doesn’t find the keyword,
the `IF(…)` function evaluates to a null string. 
(If you want a case-sensitive comparison, replace `SEARCH` with `FIND`.) 
Then, either way,
the result is concatenated to the value from the cell to the left. 
This yields, in Column `K`,
a comma-separated list of the keywords that are present
in the paragraph in Column `A` of the current row.

Then enter

```
=IF(K2="", "", RIGHT(K2, LEN(K2)-2))
```

into `E2`, and drag/fill down to cover the rows that have data in Column `A`. 
This says, if the value in Column `K` is null, then evaluate to null,
otherwise strip off the `,`  from the beginning of the value in Column `K`.

Here’s an image of the result I got for your input data:

[image: spreadsheet]
[(Click for a larger image.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqaT0.png)

Note in cell `E6` (the output for`A6`) that my solution
lists the matching keywords in the order they appear in Column `C`,
whereas your illustration lists them in the order they appear in cell `A6`. 
If that’s a problem, edit your question to say so, and I’ll see if I can fix it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the edit and for the answer. Your approach works great. The problem is that I have _700k keywods_ (and ever more _text_, that's why R is a pain in the a**) so, is there any way to do this without using a column for each keyword? In R, I took the list of keywords and concatenated it with an OR operator _in a single cell_, then match it against each _text_. I looked for this in Excel and found that TEXTJOIN does the concatenation easily, but don't know about the rest. PS: About your final question, using the order of `C` is not a problem.

Comment: I just found about [Excel specifications](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3) so concatenate the _keywords_ like that in a single cell is not an option. Maybe I need to look into macros? It should be a simple loop.